# Add/remove vehicles in SUMO via TraCI at runtime

Tags: python, sumo

I know that traci.vehicle API has an add and a remove function which is just **traci vehicle remove or traci vehicle add**. I am using SUMO on Windows. I have the network, the routes and a fixed number of 37000 vehicles in the network. I started my simulation in python and tried to remove a vehicle  as follows when simulation is running:

```
import traci 
traci.start(sumoCmd)
stepz = 0
while traci.simulation.getMinExpectedNumber() > 0 and stepz < 7000:
   traci.simulationStep()
   traci.vehicle.remove("2773")
traci.close()
```

When I run this I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 9, in 
>       traci.vehicle.remove("2773")
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci_vehicle.py", line 1579, in remove
>       tc.CMD_SET_VEHICLE_VARIABLE, tc.REMOVE, vehID, reason)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\connection.py", line 149, in _sendByteCmd
>       self._sendExact()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\Sumo\tools\traci\connection.py", line 112, in _sendExact
>       raise TraCIException(err, prefix[1], _RESULTS[prefix[2]])
>     TraCIException: Vehicle '2773' is not known.

"2773" is one of the vehicle's ID I got from my **mytrip.trips.xml** file. I don't know what is wrong with this piece of code and how to fix it. I also would like to know how should I find the **RouteID** to add a vehicle.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is (as Michael pointed out) that you are trying to remove a vehicle that is not in the simulation yet. The vehicle with ID `"2773"` is only defined in your `.rou.xml` file. SUMO parses the `.rou.xml` file in runtime and loads the vehicles while the simulation is running. The vehicle is not yet in the simulation because it is either defined to depart at a different time or it is currently trying to enter the network but there are more vehicles before it (it's queued up).

The solution is to check whether the vehicle has departed already:

```py
if "2773" in traci.vehicle.getIDList():
    traci.vehicle.remove("2773")
```

or, try to remove and catch:

```py
try:
    traci.vehicle.remove("2773")
except TraCIException:
    pass  # just do nothing
```

As for your question in the comment about adding `route`. The `"1"` in line `traci.route.add("1", ["5367021#0", "-133806981#1"])` is a new ID which you are trying to assign to a route consisting of edges `"5367021#0"` and `"-133806981#1"`. Make sure you are not adding the same route again. The route id must be unique. In many cases, command is being executed repeatedly in a loop which causes the error.

You can find everything you need in the documentation here: https://sumo.dlr.de/pydoc/

Comment: How can I remove a number of vehicles? Like is there any way to remove them in a "for" loop or something similar?

Comment: Of course, you can do it using the code from the answer. E.g. to remove all vehicles:
for veh in traci.vehicle.getIDList():
    traci.vehicle.remove(veh)

Comment: In case of adding new vehicle, I've tried different way to specify consecutive edges but I literally don't know what's the problem. I also followed one of the vehicle in my simulation and copied all the edges it took as its route and put them in my code in a correct order but the simulation got stuck immediately and I see this error message "TraCIException: Could not add route." Would you please advise me?

Comment: Maybe you missed one edge which is very very small. I recommend opening the net in netedit and observe your wanted route in more detail. Firstly try to build very short route (e.g. only three edges) and see if you can add the route via traci. If you succeed, then try to build bigger routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove a vehicle which is already in the network. So maybe your vehicle has not yet departed. The route id is the id of the route either from an XML definition or from an earlier traci.route.add call.

Comment: How do I make sure that the vehicle is departed? and what is "trip" in traci.route.add("trip", ["startEdge", "endEdge"])?

Comment: Also when I try to add my new vehicle "5000" with these lines traci.route.add("1", ["25367021#0", "-133806981#1"]) and traci.vehicle.add("5000", "1") I receive this error message: "TraCIException: Could not add route." I right clicked on my lane in SUMO GUI and copied edge to clipboard and pasted it in my python script. Did I do something wrong? I got the same error for any edge I put there.